# Got a compilation problem with dart null safety

Tags: flutter, dart-null-safety

I am new to flutter null safety and I can't manage how to have no compilation error.
This is the (incomplete) code

```
GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
Scaffold(
  key: _scaffoldKey
);
...
showDialog(context: _scaffold.currentContext)
```

showdialog is waiting for a non null BuildContext so I got the error:

```
The argument type 'BuildContext?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'BuildContext'
```

Help please!

Comment: just add a ! to BuildContext?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you sure that `_scaffold.currentContext` can never be null:

```
GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
Scaffold(
  key: _scaffoldKey
);
...
showDialog(context: _scaffold.currentContext!) //Add "!" here and the problem is solved
```

Comment: Thank you guy. I have understand that I need to add ! at the end of the whole variable !

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
//@dart=2.9
```

in line 1 of main.dart file